# Unable to push local files to gitlab repo getting access denied

Tags: git-push

I am trying to push code files from my local system to gitlab repo.
When I am running `git push -u -f gitlab main`, I am getting error as `access denied. The provided password or token is incorrect or your account has 2fa enabled and you must use a personal access token instead of a password`.

On trying to push files from local system on git bash Inam getting the below error on running `git push -u -f gitlab main` even though I am giving correct credentials in the gitlab pop up for entering username & password.